# Websockets proxies and using port 443 simultanously with IIS web server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, websocket

I have read a lot about websockets and reverse proxy and so on, but till now I have not get any satisfying solution or answer.

1. If I want to use websockets and my webserver on the same port (80 or 443) is there a possibility to let it work with IIS? I know there are changes after IIS 8, but what with previous versions,and how to configure it in IIS 8?
2. Every server I configure can have another url, or even have a proxy to navigate over. So can I configure my javascript client so, that it will always reach the websocket server? 
   I know I could do something like:

   var url = ws://" + window.location.hostname + ":12345";

but what if there is a proxy, will this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

IIS versions prior 8 do not support WebSockets. If you want to have websockets you need to host it in another process, of course in another port.

IIS8 can handle websockets on the same ports than you web application. You can have a different websockets endpoints in the same ASP.NET application, like one in /sports/soccer to get updates about soccer and other in /sports/golf to get updates about golf, they would have different handlers if you want.

About proxies, please read [How HTML5 Web Sockets Interact With Proxy Servers](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers). Basically, if you use WSS:// you are fine most of the times.